# Warsaw theme - Frame title bar covers top infolines

Tags: beamer, color, themes, gradient

I'm making a presentation using `Warsaw` theme, but with `infolines` at the top of every frame. The problem is that `\frametitle` command makes the title bar to cover part of the top infolines bar, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I thought of two solutions:

- shifting down the title bar in the `Warsaw` theme;
- choose another theme and add the gradient myself (with the same colors as Warsaw theme).

I'm new to `beamer`, so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This bug has been fixed in `beamer` version 3.23, so the fix provided in this answer shouldn't be necessary any more!

This is most likely a `beamer` bug, which was [already reported](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/173), but closed as not reproducible. A workaround is to shift the frame title down as you suggested, which can be done by using

```
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}
```

after having loaded `Warsaw` and `infolines`.

#### Example code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

% fix clipped headline (bug with Warsaw/infolines)
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip2pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Warsaw and infolines, overlapping headline fixed]

Comment: I commented on the [bug report](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/173/warsaw-theme-conflicting-with-infolines), providing a link to this question and a MWE.