# Add title at the beginning of the slide

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Well, this is probably stupid question, but I can't find any answer. I use the Warsaw theme and there is that blue box on the title slide with the title of the work. I want to add that blue box, but with different text, to the other slides and I want to write text after that. Simply said - how do I add a big title to the top of the slide and then write text below it.

This is what I was able to do, but it's terrible.
[image: bad-looking slide title]

Comment: Instead of only showing the result, you could also show us how you did it. Did you try with `\begin{frame}{Some title here} ... \end{frame}`? This is how titles are included in frames. If you don't like the result, you should try with another theme or ask how to adapt it to your taste. Both are different problems. Could you rephrase your question and make it more clear? By the way: "Welcome to TeX.SX!"

Comment: @Ignasi Yes, I used \begin{frame}{Some title here} ... \end{frame}. But I meant it like - is there easy way to make custom slide title like in powerpoint presentation, but not based on used theme? I at least found out how to change colors in it, but still, I would like to know how to create custom slide title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but if you want frametitles like on the titlepage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{Beamer Presentation}
\author{\LaTeX  Enthusiast}
\date{today}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
    \@tempdima=\textwidth%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
    \vskip1ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]{frametitle}
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
        \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@ftecenter\endcsname\fi%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
        {%
            \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \else%
            {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
            \fi
        }%
        \vskip-1ex%
        \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Frame title}
      test
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this -  MWE would have helped

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}


\title{Beamer Presentation}
\author{\LaTeX  Enthusiast}
\date{today}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{First Section}

    \begin{frame}{Title of the frame \ldots a little longer}

        Hello World and your text.

    \end{frame}

%   Or you can use \frametitle as explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51518/warsaw-theme-frame-title-bar-covers-top-infolines
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame title}
    \end{frame}



\end{document}
```